# Firebase server key квоты и время жизни?

Tags: android, firebase, sendmessage, fcm, messaging

Пишем проект под android/ios с использованием FCM Firebase message. Хотелось бы узнать, какое время жизни серверного ключа api fcm, а также, сколько устройств может выступать в роли отправителя ? По поводу life цикла токенов клиентов понятно,токен обновляется в основном либо при удалении и повторной установке приложения, либо по желанию google,где можно отловить момент tokenRefresh и успеть передать на свой сервер новый токен клиента.А почему обновляется серверный ключ? Как можно отследить момент того ,что он перегенерирован google? И также сопутствующий вопрос, сколько устройств могут быть отправителями? То есть сколько  например android устройств могут  слать по http запросам месседжи клиентам с content-type: application/json  и авторизацией key="your server key FCM"?

Comment: Мне кажется, вы неверно понимаете роль "вашего сервера" в контексте FCM. Сервер FCM не подразумевает что к нему начнут массово коннектиться с разных IP используя серверный ключ. Возможно поэтому и срабатывает защита типа "ключ скомпроментирован" на стороне Google.

Comment: Серверный Ключ в моем случае не менялся. Узнаю на будущее. То что ключ скромпроментирован на стороне google нигде нет информации официальной.Квот на кол-во подключений и ограничений на использование api тоже мало официальной инфы. По поводу неправильного понимания, не согласен, такой концепции требует бизнес логика проекта. Хотя конечно, судя по вашему сообщению, можно сделать отдельный прокси сервис,слать только с него на fcm api запросы.А со всех устройств отправителей ссылаться не напрямую,а на этот прокси. Но такой вариант менее нам нравится.

Comment: Но такой вариант и есть правильный.